# Zabbix - wildcard usage in perf_counter

Tags: wildcard, zabbix

colleges!

I really need to use wildcard in perf_counter.

We have .NET Data Provider for SqlServer counters. Unfortunately, the ID on counter changes after each reboot.

Right now I have counter like this:

```
perf_counter["\.NET Data Provider for SqlServer(_lm_w3svc_3_root-3-131958133162924330[18196])\NumberOfActiveConnectionPools"]
```

How can I use it permanently. Maybe I need to use a wildcard like this:

```
perf_counter["\.NET Data Provider for SqlServer(_lm_w3svc_3_root-3-131958133162924330[*])\NumberOfActiveConnectionPools"]
```

The counter became unsupported with "Cannot obtain performance information from collector".

I really need your help!
Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/perfcounters) doesn't mention wildcards with performance counters.

If your counter changes at every reboot you need to use a discovery rule even if you're dealing with a single item.

The discovery rule could be a powershell script like:

```
$result = @{}
$result.data = @()

(get-counter -Listset *).paths | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_ -Like "*_lm_w3svc_3_root-3-131958133162924330*\NumberOfActiveConnectionPools") { 
        $result.data += @{
            "{#PATH}" = $_
        }
    }
} 

$result | ConvertTo-Json
```

Set it to run every hour or less and create an item prototype like `perf_counter["{#PATH}"]`, this should do the trick.